# http server respnd with an output from an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, httpresponse

I want my http respond script to respond with data from my SQL server. So I can use AJAX to update HTML with data from my SQL server. And I cant find a way to do this. I'm just learning about async and I have a feeling that if I can save the output of my async function to a global var then it will work. Any help would save my headache.

My simple Listen script is:

```
var test = "hello!"

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write(test);
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

and my sql code is:

```
const util = require('util');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "XXXXX",
    user: "XXXXX",
    password: "XXXXX",
    database: "XXX"
  });

var DBresult=null;

function getdb(){
  const query = util.promisify(con.query).bind(con);
  (async () => {
    try {
      const rows = await query('SELECT * FROM mylist');
      DBresult=rows;
     
    } finally {
      con.end();
    }
  })()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT use any globals or shared, higher scoped variables for your asynchronous result in a server.  Never do that. That is an anti-pattern for good reason because that can create intermittent concurrency problems because more than one request can be in process at the same time on your server so these would cause conflicting access to those variables, creating intermittent, very-hard-to-debug problems.  I repeat again, NEVER.

You didn't describe an exact situation you are trying to write code for, but here's an example.

Instead, you use the result inside the context that it arrives from your asynchronous call.  If you can use `await`, that generally makes the coding cleaner.

Here's a simple example:

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "XXXXX",
    user: "XXXXX",
    password: "XXXXX",
    database: "XXX"
});

const query = util.promisify(con.query).bind(con);

http.createServer(async function(req, res) {
    if (req.path === "/query" && req.method === "GET") {
        try {
            const rows = await query('SELECT * FROM mylist');
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.end();
        }
    } else {
        // some other respone
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.write("hello");
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Things to note here:

1. Checking both path and method before handling the request.
2. Making callback function `async` so it can use `await`.
3. Making sure any promise rejection from `await` is caught by `try/catch` and an error response is sent if there's an error.
4. Sending result as JSON and setting appropriate content-type.
5. You may be using the plain `http` module as a learning experience, but you will very quickly find that using the simple [Express framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) will save you lots of programming time and make things lots easier.

Comment: I had never thought of that issue with a global var Thanks! To give you some background, I am making a webpage that will add a new card for every row in my SQL database. But i need to use AJAX for the client to request table data from a nodejs application. I will look into Express framework now. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use async functions, it would be something like this, take care of "async" in function for the createServer

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
    async function mgetdata() {
        // Async code goes here
        return 'Hello, world!';
    }

    // Wait for the async function to complete and get its return value
    const response = await mgetdata();

    // Send the response
    res.end(response);
});
```